# Discrete mathematic: Equivalence laws question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm preparing for a college class in discrete math and I'm trying to understand the material early by doing some practice problems. An example I picked up around campus involves "set identities" such as the Associative law and De Morgan's laws. I apologize if there's already a post that explains this, but discrete math just goes over my head right now. If it helps, the book my campus uses is *Discrete Mathematics with Applications, 7th Edition* by Ken Rosen.

Here's how the question goes: "Let A, B, and C be sets. Use set identities and the expression $A-B = A \cap \bar B$ to simplify $[B\cup(A \cap \bar B)]-[(B-A)\cap(C-B)]$. Name what identity you're using in each step."

How would I simplify that?

Comment: by $\bar B $, do you mean the complement of $B$? It is good to clarify, similar notation is sometimes used for other things.

Comment: You could start by applying the definition of $A - B$ and applying distributivity and De Morgan's laws.

Comment: In fact, the just the definition of $A - B$ and basic properties like $X \cap \bar{X} = \emptyset$ and $X \cup (Y - X) = X \cup Y$ will see you through.

Comment: Yes, $\bar B$ is the complement of B. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{aligned} \left[B\cup(A\cap \bar{B})\right]-[(B-A)\cap(C-B)]\\=[B\cup(A\cap \bar{B})]\cap\overline{[(B-A)\cap(C-B)]}\\=[(B\cup A)\cap(B\cup\bar{B})]\cap[\overline{(B-A)}\cup\overline{C-B)}]\\=[(B\cup A)]\cap[(\bar{B}\cup A)\cup (\bar{C}\cup B)]\\=(B\cup A)\cap(\bar{B}\cup B\cup A\cup C)\\=B\cup A\end{aligned}$

Here, first step is using $A\cap\bar{B}=A-B$, second and third use De-Morgan's laws and the fact that $A\cup\bar{A}=X$, where $X$ is the universal set.

Comment: Okay, I can see how $B \cup \bar B$ would cancel each other out, but how did you get rid of the $A \cup C$?

Comment: @009 Any subset union the universal set is the universal set